# Import/assemble RAID0 using Ubuntu 14

Tags: dmraid

I know this question probably came up before, but I could not find the answer. I have two 1TB HDD setup in RAID 0, but the motherboard went bad. I replaced the motherboard and installed Ubuntu 14 on a new drive. The two 1TB HDD are connected in SATA port without using RAID in BIOS. I was hoping Ubuntu can see the RAID0 volume automatically, as some has mentioned on the Net, but I guess I wasn't one of the lucky. Here's the info on the screen, and I would appreciate it if someone can help (sda is where Ubuntu is installed, sdb and sdc are the two disks in RAID0, sdc is a USB drive for data storage)

```
ning@ning-desktop:~$ sudo fdisk -l
[sudo] password for ning:

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device Boot Start End Blocks Id System
/dev/sda1 1 976773167 488386583+ ee GPT

Disk /dev/sdb: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00027aba

Disk /dev/sdb doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/sdc: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x46456bf4

Device Boot Start End Blocks Id System
/dev/sdc1 * 2048 614402047 307200000 7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdc2 614402048 1843202047 614400000 7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdc3 1843202048 3072002047 614400000 7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdc4 3072002048 3907035135 417516544 7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
Note: sector size is 4096 (not 512)

Disk /dev/sdd: 3000.6 GB, 3000592977920 bytes
1 heads, 63 sectors/track, 11628041 cylinders, total 732566645 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x16235d7f

Device Boot Start End Blocks Id System
/dev/sdd1 63 732564062 2930256000 7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT


ning@ning-desktop:~$ sudo dmraid -ay
ERROR: unsupported sector size 4096 on /dev/sdd.
RAID set "isw_hfdfaihhf_HDDRAID0" was not activated
```

Comment: There exists no such release named "Ubuntu 14". The number is not a traditional version number that can be rounded. So don't do that unless you want to specifically state that you use an unsupported release (in that case why are you even asking here?). http://askubuntu.com/q/204352/40581

Answer (score 0):

What software RAID solution are you using? mdadm or dmraid/fakeraid (which would still be dependent on the controller)? Also you don't seem to want to recover data from a failed RAID0. Putting such a wording in the title of your question wouldn't make you look very smart or make other users around here care.

## Analysis

```
ning@ning-desktop:~$ sudo dmraid -ay
[…]
RAID set "isw_hfdfaihhf_HDDRAID0" was not activated
```

Okay, dmraid found a raidset but didn't activate it. Let's find out why.

> sdb and sdc are the two disks in RAID0, sdc is a USB drive for data storage

There is obviously something wrong here.

- `Disk /dev/sdb: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes`

  Disk with 1TB capacity, check. Something indicating that this device is part of some kind of software RAID?

  ```
  Disk /dev/sdb doesn't contain a valid partition table
  ```

  While this is possible with mdadm, it is not recommended. With zfs (and probably btrfs too) there would have been a partition table, so I guess we are searching for some kind of mdadm compatible format (have a look at the `--metadata` parameter on the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/mdadm.8.html) for a listing of formats). I don't know about how dmraid/fakeraid handles this, as I don't recommend using it.
- `Disk /dev/sdc: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes`

  Disk with 1TB capacity, check. But this can't possibly be the disk of the RAID set we are looking for as this contains partitions indicating that this is possibly a Windows installation and it has a different sector size.

  ```
  Device Boot Start End Blocks Id System
  /dev/sdc1 * 2048 614402047 307200000 7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
  /dev/sdc2 614402048 1843202047 614400000 7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
  /dev/sdc3 1843202048 3072002047 614400000 7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
  /dev/sdc4 3072002048 3907035135 417516544 7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
  Note: sector size is 4096 (not 512)
  ```
- `Disk /dev/sdd: 3000.6 GB, 3000592977920 bytes`

  Like sda not the disk we're looking for as it isn't a drive of 1TB capacity. This might be the USB drive mentioned above.

## Conclusion

- You are not telling us the full story.

  - You have another 1TB drive that is currently not attached to the machine. Attach it and try again.
  - You probably wiped one half of the set by installing another operating system.
- Don't ever use RAID0 for important data.